# How to split a PDF based on a size limit?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox

I have searched many places but unable to find a pretty good solution as such.
So what I am trying to achieve is as below:
My program will have quite a lot of PDF docs which I will have to send via mail. There is a mail server limitation of 4 MB. So if all the PDFs are less than 4 MB it will be sent as a single mail. Else I will have to create multiple files each less than 4 MB. 
Now my program works fine for the following cases:
1: Lots of files but each less than 4MB and hence keeping a tab during merging so that none of the merged files get over 4MB.
2: All files are pretty small and hence merging them together does not go to 4MB limit.

But there can be a scenario where there is one file which is, say, 14MB. I can split that document by pages. But that is also not a good solution as the pagesize is also not evenly distributed across the pages. I have used iText and PDFBox. Any help/pointer will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a 3000 KB document with ten pages and the following objects:

- four font subsets used on every page, each about 50 KB
- ten images that figure on a single page, each about 200 KB (one image per page)
- four images that figure on every page, each about 50 KB
- ten pages with content streams of about 25 KB each
- about 350 KB for objects such as the catalog, the info dictionary, the page tree, the cross-reference table, etc...

A single page will need at least:
- the four font subsets: 4 times 50 KB
- the single image: 1 time 200 KB
- the four images: 4 times 50 KB
- a single content stream: 1 time 50 KB
- a slightly reduced cross-reference table, a slightly reduced page tree, an almost identical catalog, an info dictionary of identical size,... 200 KB

Together that's 850 KB. This means that you end up with 8500 KB (10 times 850 KB) if you split up a 10-page 3000 KB PDF document into 10 separate pages.

This example is the result of guess work (based on experience) and it assumes that the PDF is predictable. Most PDFs aren't:

- some pages will require high-definition images (maybe even megaBytes), other pages won't have any images,
- some pages will need many different fonts and font subsets (lots of kiloBytes), other pages will consist of merely some vector drawings (tiny content stream if compressed).
- different pages can share a large amount of resources (Form XObjects, Image XObjects,...), other pages won't share any resources.
- and so on...

You have noticed that yourself, as you write: *I can split that document by pages. But that is also not a good solution as the pagesize is also not evenly distributed across the pages.*

That's exactly why your question can have no other answer than: you'll have to do *trial and error.* No software can predict how much space is needed by a page before you look at what is needed by that page.

**Update:**

As David indicates in the comments, it is possible to calculate all the resources needed for a page, and to check if the current resources plus the needed resources exceed the maximum file size.

I have written a small example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        // check resources needed for reader.getPageN(i);
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, i));
        System.out.println("After adding page: " + copy.getOs().getCounter());
    }
    document.close();
    System.out.println("After closing document: " + copy.getOs().getCounter());
    reader.close();
}
```

I have executed the example on a PDF sample with 18 pages and this was the output:

```
After adding page: 56165
After adding page: 111398
After adding page: 162691
After adding page: 210035
After adding page: 253419
After adding page: 273429
After adding page: 330696
After adding page: 351564
After adding page: 400351
After adding page: 456545
After adding page: 495321
After adding page: 523640
After adding page: 576468
After adding page: 633525
After adding page: 751504
After adding page: 907490
After adding page: 957164
After adding page: 999140
After closing document: 1002509
```

You see how the file size of the copy gradually grows with each page that is added. After all pages are added, the size is 999140 bytes, and then the page tree and cross-reference stream are written, adding another 3369 bytes.

Where it says `// check resources needed for reader.getPageN(i);`, you could make a guesstimate of the size that will be added for the page and break out of the loop if it exceeds a maximum value.

Why would this be a guesstimate:

1. You could be counting objects that are already added. If you keep track of the objects (not that difficult), your guess will be more accurate.
2. I'm using `PdfSmartCopy`. Suppose that there are two identical objects inside your PDF. Bad PDF software often causes such problems. For instance: the same image bytes are added twice to the file. `PdfSmartCopy` can detect this and will reuse the first object it encounters instead of adding the redundant bytes of the extra object.

We currently don't have a `reader.getTotalPageBytes()` in `PdfReader` because `PdfReader` tries to use as little memory as possible. It won't load any objects into memory as long as these objects aren't needed. Hence it doesn't know the size of each object before the page is imported.

However, I'll make sure that such a method is added in the next release.

**Update:**

In the next version, you'll find a tool named [`SmartPdfSplitter`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6802/) that depends on a new class named [`PdfResourceCounter`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/6800). You can use it like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
SmartPdfSplitter splitter = new SmartPdfSplitter(reader);
int part = 1;
while (splitter.hasMorePages()) {
    splitter.split(new FileOutputStream("results/merge/part_" + part + ".pdf"), 200000);
    part++;
}
reader.close();
```

Note that this can result in a single-page PDF that exceeds the limit (which was set to `200000` bytes in the code sample) in case that single page can not be reduced to less bytes. In that case, `splitter.isOverSized()` will return `true` and you'll have to find another way to reduce the PDF.

Comment: Sir, you just confirmed my doubt! Thanks a lot! I will change my design.

Comment: I don't get why you would call this impossible - you're right that it's hard, but software could actually do these calculations and come up with the correct answer, no?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche maybe Bruno's hypertrophic ego thinks that there's nothing but iText in the universe of PDF software: anything iText can't do CANNOT be done by whatsoever other software, by definition! ;-) (just kiddin'!)

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche it's not even hard to implement such a calculation -- when software is well-written, it allows you to do powerful things with (comparatively) little effort: PDF Clown's page data size prediction algorithm takes a mere 20 lines of clean code! It performs a model traversal taking into account page's shared resources: without any strange hacking, you can incrementally simulate the size of a document and, when you judge it's ok, you can do the actual write.

Comment: @StefanoChizzolini As iText is well-written, it will be no problem to add this feature in the next iText release. I see that you also challenge my ego. I accept the challenge. If you're a PDF expert, you'll be at the ISO committee meetings at the Adobe Headquarters in San Jose (California) from April 19 to April 24. Let's meet there and talk. If you aren't there, nor anyone from your company, I'll assume that PDF isn't that important to you, as you are not contributing to the upcoming PDF 2.0 standard ;-)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I was challenging your categorical assumption about trial and error; now your update has corrected it, so I can just agree with your solution (waiting for proactive resource check implementation).

Comment: I'm leaving for California this weekend. I could ask the iText staff to implement this, but it will be fun to do this myself ;-) This being said, are you going to join the ISO committee, @StefanoChizzolini ?

Comment: "If you aren't there, nor anyone from your company, I'll assume that PDF isn't that important to you, as you are not contributing to the upcoming PDF 2.0 standard ;-)" That's very low, Bruno, and very borderline an insult. It certainly doesn't have any place on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Obviously, not: I'm among the thousands of software professionals which expect the committee will hopefully do the right job. ;-)

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I was once in Stefano's position: I had a simple PDF library and no business model (2000). I made money with my day job, not with iText. Thousands of people were using it, but only a handful were contributing. AFAIK that's also the case for PdfClown now. Then my son got Cancer (2008), and iText was almost abandoned. Copycats emerged. That hurt. But then I found a business model (2009) and I started making money with iText. I hired a staff (we're about 20 people now) and iText became the most widely used PDF library. When Stefano made fun of that, I returned the favor ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**[PDF Clown](http://pdfclown.org/)** supports *[page data size prediction without need of trial and error](http://pdfclown.org/2010/09/23/waiting-for-pdf-clown-0-1-release/)*: since 2010 it has been featuring a dedicated method ([org.pdfclown.tools.PageManager.getSize(Page)](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/tools/PageManager.html#getSize%28org.pdfclown.documents.Page%29)) that calculates in memory the actual page data size without the need to write it to a file for trial.

Furthermore, there's another method ([org.pdfclown.tools.PageManager.split(long maxDataSize)](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/tools/PageManager.html#split%28long%29)) purposely implemented to address your kind of scenario which leverages the above-mentioned PageManager.getSize method: *it automatically splits a file based on a size limit without creating any intermediate, ugly, stupid, temporary file for trial and error*.

You can see a practical example of its use in the org.pdfclown.samples.cli.PageManagementSample (PageDataSizeCalculation and DocumentSplitOnMaximumFileSize cases) included in the downloadable distribution -- here it is an example of console output from the PageDataSizeCalculation case:

```
Page 1: 29380 (full); 29380 (differential); 29380 (incremental)
Page 2: 30493 (full); 1501 (differential); 30881 (incremental)
Page 3: 21888 (full); 1432 (differential); 32313 (incremental)
Page 4: 33781 (full); 4789 (differential); 37102 (incremental)
. . .
```

where:

- *full* is the page data size encompassing all its dependencies (like shared resources) -- this is the size of the page when extracted as a single-page document;
- *differential* is the additional page data size -- this is the extra content that's not shared with previous pages;
- *incremental* is the data size of the page sublist encompassing all the previous pages and the current one.

Comment: Considering that pages may share resources, is there also a method calculating the memory requirements of a selection of pages counting such shared resources but once?

Comment: @mkl yes, for sure: there's an overload of org.pdfclown.tools.PageManager.getSize (getSize(Page page, Set<PdfReference> visitedReferences), see http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/tools/PageManager.html#getSize%28org.pdfclown.documents.Page,%20java.util.Set%29) which keeps track of shared resources avoiding duplications (it's also used by the implementation of org.pdfclown.tools.PageManager.split(long)).

Comment: Ok, then the feature sounds usable and useful.

Comment: BTW, I assume that means that object streams are not used for optimal compression by PDF Clown. A [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28624660/1729265) in the context of PDF Box shows that their use can make quite a difference concerning the resulting size. I'm not sure, though, whether any general purpose PDF lib makes use of that PDF feature at all.

Comment: PDF Clown supports R/W object streams and can preserve them on saving a file (like the case you referenced). However,considering the case on topic, your assumption is correct: PageManager.split() doesn't use object streams to achieve further compression (BTW, I tried it on the 6MB sample file of the PDF Box case and the result was quite good: 6 1MB files -- maybe a significant portion of the overhead was due to data not directly correlated to the pages (I didn't investigate further)). Anyway, you made a good point: I'll evaluate the convenience to squeeze the last bytes through object streams.

Comment: *I'll evaluate the convenience to squeeze the last bytes through object streams.* - in case of documents like in the linked issue, that would mean quite a lot. I don't know, though, how representative they are for the use cases you focus PDF clown on.

Comment: The intention is always to be able to cope with the most disparate cases but, you know, the variance of the PDF realm is almost overwhelming :-)