# In PDFBox, why does file size becomes extremely large after saving?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

**Question**

I am using PDFBox 1.8.8 to manipulate existing PDF files.  After saving a document, the output file becomes several times larger than the original.  This is undesirable.

How can I reduce the file size of output files?

**How to replicate my situation**

In the following code, PDFBox simply loads an existing PDF and then save it.  Nothing else is done.  Yet the file size still becomes several times larger.

Below are links to two sample input files.  For input1.pdf, file size increases from 6MB to 50MB.  For input2.pdf, file size increases from 0.4MB to 1.3MB.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13566649/samplePDF/input1.pdf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13566649/samplePDF/input2.pdf

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.*;


class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("input1.pdf");
        document.save("output.pdf");
        document.close();       
    }
}
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried using `addCompression()` method of `PDStream` class, as in the following code.  It does not change anything.  Output file size is still the same.

```
class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load("input1.pdf");

        for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(i);
            page.getContents().addCompression();
        }

        document.save("output.pdf");
        document.close();    

    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend that you open an issue in PDFBox JIRA and attach the smaller file. There's an enormous amount of "structure" information that is compressed in the initial file, but not in the saved one.

Comment: I meant the object stream.

Comment: I've created an JIRA issue for this.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2690

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same issue, have you find a solution? I also tried to use a PDStream.addCompression but with the same results :( Is there another library which implements this splitting in a better wary?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this strange code and it works for me ([Apache PDFBox v.2.0.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/2.0.8)):

```
private void saveCompressedPDF(PDDocument srcDoc, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    PDDocument outDoc = new PDDocument();
    outDoc.setDocumentInformation(srcDoc.getDocumentInformation());
    for (PDPage srcPage : srcDoc.getPages()) {
        new PDPageContentStream(outDoc, srcPage,
                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true).close();
        outDoc.addPage(srcPage);
    }
    outDoc.save(os);
    outDoc.close();
}
```

Comment: what do you add an empty content stream to each page for?

Comment: The smaller size you'd get on the attached files with your code may be because your code doesn't copy the structure tree.

Comment: Exactly the same file size 2.0.17