# Adobe PDFBox produces unexpected changes for load followed by save

Tags: java, file, pdf, pdfbox

I'm working on a tool to automatically generate PDF files based on a template file and other source data. I'm using Mac OS 10.14.4, Java 1.8 and PDFBox version 2.0.15.

As a basic test, I trimmed the open-and-save code down to two lines, which have an obvious problem for one particular PDF and more subtle issues for all other PDFs I've tried:

```
PDDocument targetPDF = PDDocument.load(new File(templatePath));
targetPDF.save(targetFileName)
```

The observed problem *for one particular PDF* is that unexpected characters are inserted at the top of the first page. (They appear to be in an alphabet which is not otherwise used, and are clipped.) Other PDFs are visually similar, but very different when I run them through `diff`. Is this something tricky I should do to save the files? Is this a problem with that one file? Is PDFBox is doing something odd?

I've looked for similar reports, and found a few that are concerned with the size of the output files:  [In PDFBox, why does file size becomes extremely large after saving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624660/in-pdfbox-why-does-file-size-becomes-extremely-large-after-saving) and [Split and merge pdf files using PDFBOX produces large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045571/split-and-merge-pdf-files-using-pdfbox-produces-large-file) I do see a noticeable increase in file size, but not as much as those questions report. In *one* case, the input and output files are visually different. In others, `diff -y --text template.pdf target.pdf` reports large differences but I don't detect any differences by eye alone. (In Mac's built-in "Preview" document viewer. The breaking "template.pdf" is created in Adobe Acrobat. I don't know about the non-breaking files.)

After comparison to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2690 and http://useof.org/java-open-source/org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject I tried adding `targetPDF.close()` after the `targetPDF.save()`, but that made no difference.
https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html seems to suggest closing a *content* *stream* before saving the file, but I don't know how to do that. (`File` itself doesn't have a `close()` method. None of the methods on PDDocument seem related to streams or closing them, except `PDDocument.close()` itself, which prevents saving.)

I would paste in some log files here, but I'm not getting any log messages from PDFBox classes....

Comment: We'd need the PDF to find what is going on. Maybe the PDF was broken, PDFBox repaired it and stuff that wasn't displayed by Adobe is displayed now. Also try whether the effect happens with older versions. Btw that the file itself is different is normal. That the rendering is different, not.

Comment: P.S. your code is fine.

Comment: Just to second @Tilman - the file really is needed for an analysis. But chances are that he's right, the file likely is broken to start with and your pdf viewer and pdfbox interpret the broken pieces differently during repair. And indeed, the original and the re-saved pdf files as binary data can be completely different.

Comment: Do you get any log output (check that logs are not disabled)? And does the "extra text" also appear when looking at the file with PDFDebugger?

Comment: The original PDF is corporate property, but I was hoping that it being made with Acrobat would have prevented corrupt data...  I'll check with my manager on whether I can publish it. I don't have any logs from the PDF classes. I'll see what I can do about that...  I'll have to research how to activate them and where those files get stored or written. (Any advice or references? I'm currently running the Java code via Gradle, and the classes I wrote are using slf4j. I found unhelpful pages on log4j configuration...) I've never used PDF Debugger, but will see what I can learn about it.

Comment: Hi guys, and thanks for your help. I've got an early draft of my code working now. I created an additional trial PDF (through Word) and was able to swap out one image. It was very helpful to me to know the input and output files weren't expected to be identical, that my tiny snippet of code wasn't missing something, and that corrupted PDFs from Acrobat are possible. If @Tilman wants to write that up as an official Answer, I'll be happy to accept and upvote.

Comment: "and that corrupted PDFs from Acrobat are possible" - No, files generated by Acrobat should be fine. It's more likely that it was corrupted in transfer, e.g. over a self-programmed http connection with wrong settings.  PDFDebugger (which you can get from the download page https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi ) does have a log window. So it isn't really ready for answering, your problem hasn't been solved.

Comment: I'm trying to use iText RUPS to get the logs, but am very confused - https://itextpdf.com/en/products/rups-pdf-diagnostic-tool-reading-and-updating-pdf-syntax-debugging-pdf-code shows a GUI, but doesn't offer a download of it. The only downloads I've found are iText core (I got a license key), and a library at https://github.com/itext/rups . Grepping the latter finds no reference to the LicenseKey, and even though I can build the package (by manually editing the POM to specify the version of com.itextpdf:itextpdf), `mvn site` and `mvn deploy` both fail. I'm clearly missing something basic...

Comment: PDFDebugger is not RUPS (although a video of it triggered improvements in 2015, see PDFBOX-2530) , these are different products and different organisations, and itext has nothing to do with PDFBox. I mentioned PDFDebugger in the hope that you'd get log messages on the log window. This is because sometimes some people have their logs disabled or the logs just don't show up.