# How to use IText to split by PDF by size and store into byte array

Tags: arrays, pdf, itext

I want to use IText (v7 community) to split a PDF document into different byte arrays (`byte[]`) of a smaller size, either stored as files on disk or just kept in memory for later use. Each byte array should be a valid PDF on its own.

```
  Private Sub splitmypdfbysize()
    Dim pdfDoc As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument = New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(New iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test\Test.pdf"))
    Dim splitDocuments As List(Of iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument) = (New iText.Kernel.Utils.PdfSplitter(pdfDoc).SplitBySize(5000000))
    For Each doc As iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument In splitDocuments            
        Console.WriteLine(doc.GetNumberOfPages)
        'How do I store the pdfdocument as byte arrays so that I can either write them out into files or just store it in the memory for use later?
        doc.Close()
    Next
    pdfDoc.Close()
End Sub
```

The purpose is to split big files (more than 10MB) into smaller ones so that they can be sent through email (max 10MB limit). I am aware that the total result of all the bytes sent will be more bytes in total as explained in the answer to the iText 5 question [How to split a PDF based on a size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599506)

Comment: Does each byte array need to be a valid PDF document? Or is it allowed for the byte arrays to be "broken PDFs" that can't be rendered on their own until all the byte arrays are available and can be concatenated into the original PDF? (If the latter: why is this an iText question? Why is the `PdfDocument` class relevant?)

Comment: Before you answer my question, please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28601838/1622493 to understand that splitting a 10-page 3000 KB PDF into 10 separate files could result in 10 1-page PDFs with a total size of 8500 KB. Before we answer the question, you need to be aware that splitting PDFs to reduce the file size isn't possible. You'll always end up with more bytes in total.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. The purpose is to split big files (more than 10MB) into smaller ones so that it can be sent through email (max 10MB limit). I am aware the result will be more bytes in total. Yes, each byte array needs to be a valid pdf document.